# Rails db:create failing with Postgres, claiming role doesn't exist when it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, fedora, pg

I've seen a mountain of questions related to this, but up to now none of the solutions that have worked for others have worked for myself.

presently my attempts to run 'rails db:create' are getting me the following

```
[ethannicolai@localhost EthansDevcampPortfolio]$ rails db:create --trace EDP_DB_PASSWORD='password1' RAILS_ENV=development
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
FATAL:  role "EthansDevcampPortfolio" does not exist
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"EthansDevcampPortfolio_development", "username"=>"EthansDevcampPortfolio", "password"=>"password1", "host"=>nil}
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "EthansDevcampPortfolio" does not exist
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:705:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:701:in `connect'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:220:in `initialize'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:10:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:19:in `create'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:117:in `create'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in `create_current'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "EthansDevcampPortfolio" does not exist
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:701:in `connect'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:220:in `initialize'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:759:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:803:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:782:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:743:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:10:in `connection'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:19:in `create'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:117:in `create'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in `create_current'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/share/ruby/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/home/ethannicolai/.gem/ruby/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

Within my postgres console, when I enter the \du, I get back
    ethansdevcampportfolio | Superuser, No inheritance, Create role, Create DB

I've scrutinized the user name and passwords many many times.

pg_hba.conf looks like

```
local   all         all                               trust

host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust

host    all         all         ::1/128               trust

host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0         md5(I even tried this at 'trust')
```

config/database.yml looks like

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.1 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: EthansDevcampPortfolio_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: EthansDevcampPortfolio

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: <%= ENV['EDP_DB_PASSWORD'] %>

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  host:

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: EthansDevcampPortfolio_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: EthansDevcampPortfolio_production
  username: EthansDevcampPortfolio
  password: <%= ENV['EDP_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I'm running out of ideas of places to look. I thought maybe there was a way I unwittingly installed more that one instance of postgres. I mean I'm a noob to all this, so I ran the dnf list installed and I only saw one instance of postgres there.

Any ideas of where to look, what to try or who to ask would be welcomed.

Comment: Try changing your `username` to `ethansdevcampportfolio` in `database.yml` instead of `EthansDevcampPortfolio`

Answer (score 0):

try below code in `config/database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username : db_username
  password : db_password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name
```

then run following command to create database:

```
rake db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your database doesn't have the role present. You might want  to add `EthansDevcampPortfolio` role in database or use the existing `postgres` role

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: EthansDevcampPortfolio_development
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['EDP_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the postgres console and create a superuser which has the name of your unix account (not the name of the database itself, which you have now)

```
sudo su postgres
psql
postgres=# create user ethannicolai superuser;
CREATE ROLE
```

Then when postgresql connects via unix pipe from your account, running 'rails,' you will have superuser privileges and successfully create the DB.

You can also take out the "username" and "password" fields in your config/database.yml.

While you are a superuser in the console you can also create the database you want with `create database` and then you won't need to even run db:create, but can go straight to migrating.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best solution.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s EthansDevcampPortfolio
```